# Is it possible to record screen with Titanium / Appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, desktop-recording

We're in process of developing a desktop application which needs to record user's screen once he clicks a button. I read a tutorial about Adobe AIR, which says it is easy to do with AIR: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/air_screenrecording.html

But our preference is Titanium as we've explored it a little bit. So I want to know is that even possible? If yes, how can we get started with?

There's also an interesting solution which uses Java applet for recording, as demonstrated here: http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/create?step=info&sid=default&itype=choose

But again, we're not sure about JAVA and would like to know how can it be done? or if its even possible to run a JAVA applet in Titanium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "record screen", I'm assuming you mean video. Correct?

The only way to do this in Titanium Desktop right now is to [take a bunch of screenshots](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/desktop/latest/Titanium.Platform.takeScreenshot-method) and string them together (encoding would probably need to be done server-side).

Depending on how long your videos need to be, this probably won't work for you. I'm also not confident in how quickly you could capture screenshots, and if it would have a high enough frame rate to be usable.

Past that, a module could be developed for Desktop to support some native APIs to record video. That's not something I see on the horizon, though.

I hope this helps, albiet a rather dismal answer. -Dawson